# Обновление поля в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Ребята, подскажите, как обновить поле в выборке другим полем этой же выборки?
например:

```
await this.model.updateMany({},{free_amt: amt})
```

тут я хочу, пробежать по всем записям (в каждой есть `free_amt` и `amt`) и заменить значение `free_amt` на `amt`

есть ли в mongo что-то вроде "this", чтобы обратиться к полям этой же итерации?

Answer (score 1):

тема закрыта

```
await this.model.updateMany({},[{$set: {free_amt: {$getField: "amt"}}}])
```